# Wiring question for detached room

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Would it be possible to power the detached room from the breaker box with two 30 amp breakers to the room with UF 10-2 wiring underground from the breaker box and then landed into the junction box at the room where I would join it with previously wired 12-2 wiring, one for a small 115/15 amp window unit and another for separate receptacle? 
Also, mentioning the fan switch and small appliance will be running on the same 30 amp breaker and the other receptacle to another 30 amp breaker.
 Pardon my father built this dwelling about 10 years ago and we never got around to powering the room.

Comment: Intention on using it as a "Man Cave" Taking my time on this for precautionary measures.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to  Home Improvement. It's a bit hard to understand what you mean; would you  add a diagram to your question? Thanks.

Comment: Someone will come along with full details, but *basically* what you probably should do is install a **subpanel** and then add multiple circuits for the window unit, receptacles, etc.

Comment: Don't have any diagrams created but general question is if it's okay to run a 30 amp breaker with 10-2 and join it with 12-2 at the junction box, Does that clarify any confusion you have?

Comment: When you say "detached room", are you talking about a fully independent *structure* from the main house?

Comment: Yes, the structure is 40 ft away from the main house. to be used as a small bedroom I don't have the measurements on me, but I would say it's 14x12.

Comment: @Jamieadame if any part of the circuit is 12 gauge the breaker can’t be more than 20 amp.  If you’re upsizing the underground wire to reduce voltage drop that’s fine, but if it connects to 12 gauge wire the breaker must be no larger than 20 amp.  Others are suggesting a sub-panel and that may be the best thing for you to do, but please tell us everything that might be electric so we can help with your plans.

Comment: @Tyson Okay well I intend to install the small window unit rated for 15 amps and 115v as well and the receptacle it would be plugged into is a 120v. so a 20 amp breaker would be sufficient for that unit alone? that's really my concern because I know it will draw most of the power. Apologies if this is confusing

Comment: @Jamieadame The typical solution is to run a 4-wire cable (or 4 wires in conduit, or 3 wires in metal conduit) - hot + hot + neutral + ground, with wires sized to match expected **total** load (and breaker to match in the main panel). You could then have, for example, a 40 A panel with 4 circuits - each 20A 120V - one for A/C, one for a heater, one for lights, one for other receptacles (tools, TV, whatever) and still have spare capacity. One set of wires underground (which might be bigger than you originally planned) but then future additions are entirely at the subpanel.

Comment: How big is this window unit (in BTUs)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The window unit I believe is 7,500 BTU cooling and  3,850 heating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll have to change the breakers to 20A.  You can't have 12AWG wire downline of a 30A breaker.  (NEC 240.4).

And I presume you'll want to fit common 15A or 20A receptacles, and those are only allowed on 15A or 20A circuits.  (with an exception allowing 15A receptacles on 20A circuits; no other substitutions allowed.)  NEC 210.21(B)(3).

Another problem is you're talking about running two separate 120V circuits to an outbuilding.  That is not allowed.  You can only have 1 circuit of any particular voltage, unless by nature the circuit has a special requirement e.g. a lighting circuit that needs to be switched from the main building. (NEC 225.30) You can have exactly one 120V circuit, and if you want to plug anything into it, it must be 15A or 20A. (210.21b3).  You can also have a 240V circuit.

The normal way you handle multiple circuits to an outbuilding is one single feeder that feeds a **sub-panel**.  You can only have one, but the subpanel can support any number of 120V, 120/240V, and 240V circuits.

The subpanel can be any amperage.  It can then have any number of 15A or 20A circuit breakers in the subpanel protecting individual branch circuits, or circuits of other sizes.

Comment: He could run the two circuits as a MWBC, but you pretty much might as well run a feeder at that point in time